# Mysterious device

Tags: security, google-account

I see a device in my recent security activity:

New sign-in on sdk_gphone64_x86_64
North Carolina, USA · sdk_gphone64_x86_64

I also see it in my list of Google prompts on my 2 factor authentication page.  However, I cannot remove it from my list of Google prompts and it doesn't show up in Your Devices.

I suspect this may be a test phone that I created in Android studio, but it's very worrying that it show up in the list of Google prompts on my 2 factor authentication page, but I can't get rid of it.

Comment: Can you see the devices on https://myaccount.google.com/two-step-verification/prompt? Otherwise, you need to sign out of your Google account from the emulator.

Comment: It shows up in that list, but there's no way to remove it.  I have turned off the virtual Android Phone and closed the Android Studio, but I still see it in the list.